# inline-block Nav Links won't wrap when resizing browser window

Tags: css, responsive-design

When resizing the Firefox or Chrome browser window the inline-block Nav Links won't "wrap" to a second line, etc.

Demo Code is below and is based on Using inline-block to Create Navigation Links at
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

The menu wraps properly upon resizing when it is pasted into the W3 Tryit window online
Ditto for JSFiddle

Tested it here on my Win10 Pro running iis and tested it online on linux server... in either case the menu will not wrap when I resize the browser window. (Tested it withFirefox & Chrome)

Thanks for any help.

Demo Code Below.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    .nav {
      background-image: linear-gradient(black, gary);
      list-style-type: none;
      height: auto;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      padding: .5%;   /* moves block contents away from inside edges */
    }
    
    .nav li {
      display: inline-block;
      height: auto;
      margin: .5%;   /* seperates block from things outside it */
      font-size: 150%;
      padding: .5%;   /* moves block contents away from inside edges */
      border: 1px solid #b7bdb9;
      background-color: #9bf2b3;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#clients">Our Clients</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could make a screenshot of a problem? Looks fine for me in all browsers.

Comment: Did you resize the browser window to see if the menu would "fold" to two or more lines when the browser window was narrow enough?

Comment: Yes, blocks jumped to another line just fine. Maybe i misunderstood you and you don't wont elements to do than? Do you want elements to hold a line on any width?

Comment: Go here to test it...
http://321edit.com/_nav_links_inline_blocks.php

What I want is for the menu to "wrap" to another line as I make the browser window more narrow. Let me know your results.
Let me know if it

Comment: So, back to my proposition. Can you make a screenshot, better with console on. I would like to see what is you issue looks like. Because everything looks fine for me.

Comment: Works fine. Browser windows only shrink to a certain width unless you have devtools open. If you have them open and set to left or right, you can squeeze down the window much further, and then you'll see the items wrap.

Comment: OK. That was the issue. 
In Firefox I had to click Open Menu > Web Developer > Responsive Design Mode... and it worked.
In Chrome click Customize > More Tools > Developer Tools.
Thanks for the help Tamana and Ralph.m